# passing input value as variable via <a> link

Tags: forms, variables, xampp

I am practicing in XAMPP, using an A link in a form to update some information apart from the form submit. I have checked that even if i use a button with `onclick=window.location.href` , it wont work, instead it will submit the whole form.

So i passed the variable to desired page as `href='someFile.php?variable=someValue'`. It does work this way as i can get the value through `$_GET['variable']`, i need here is also to fetch the value from  an input field (regardless of the form it is inside) to update some records.

Well, passing info via link is necessary as this "button" inside a form wont work or if can get any other way to get this process working.

In one line, the pseudo code is

```
<input type="text" name="price" /> //I cannot use another form inside a form
<a href="update_price.php?serial=123456">Update</serial>

    $serial = $_GET['serial'];
    $price = $_GET['price'];

    //I am aware of SQL Injection
    mysql_query("UPDATE items SET price='$price' WHERE serial = '$serial'");
```

I am also using jQuery library.

Thanks

Comment: Couple of things, 1) mysql_* is depecated, you should be using mysqli to keep your code working in future. 2) You DEFINITELY shouldn't be inserting any kind of request variabled directly into an SQL query without at least using http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php to sanitize it. You're putting your entire database at risk if you don't. I really hope you're not accessing he database with the root credentials either... Recipe for disaster

Comment: Thanks for the information, i didnt know about mySql depreciation. I will start coding in later one.

This is a practice code, not online.. i am fully aware of sql injection thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery you can do as follows

```
<form name = "myform">
 <textarea name="msg" id="msg"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="A submit button" />
</form>
```

This creates the form with the text box in it and a button.

You can then use script at the top like this:

```
 <script>
$(function() {
$( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
.button()
.click(function( event ) {
var text = $('textarea#msg').val();    //or
var text = $("#msg").val();
});
});
</script>
```

Which will create a jquery variable with the contents of the text field that you can then further use on the client side to process the information when the submit button it clicked.

Be aware that clients can turn off javascript at their end too so jQuery might not work.

If you need the information to be usable on the server side, you need to use AJAX
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ to asynchronously move information back to the server